# default constructor for member init?

Tags: c++, c++11

If I uncomment the line testfn causes a compile error. What constructor can I add using `=default` to allow me to define the comment out lane and still use TestFn()? Remember `t{a}` should also work (not shown below).

```
struct Test2 {
    int a; int*p;
    Test2()=default;
    //Test2(int a, int b, int c){};
};
void TestFn() { Test2 t{5,nullptr}; }
```

Comment: I think you might get more answers of useful comments for your last two questions if you tag them as C++ as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same thing happens if you explicitly define `Test2() {}`.

That form of initialization is called aggregate initialization and it only applies if there are no user-defined constructors. It does not go through any constructor but rather initializes the members directly from the braced initializer list. So there is nothing to default; you have to define explicitly any constructors you want.

Actually I feel a little surprised the explicitly-defaulted constructor doesn't disable aggregate initialization. According to @juachopanza, C++11 was specifically worded that aggregate initialization be contingent on no *definition*, allowing specifically for a *declaration.*

Comment: In C++11 there was a changing in the wording of the relevant section of the standard, from "user-declared constructor" to "user-provided constructor". This allows a defaulted constructor in an aggregate type, since it is not considered "user-provided". IIRC neither C++03 nor C++11 mention "user-defined" constructors in this context.

Comment: So there is no way I can say give me the default implementation of aggregate initialization? That's a little bad considering we can use `=default` for many other constructors. +1 but not accepted bc i'm hoping it is possible (c++14??)

Comment: @acidzombie24 Nope, it is a hole in the language IMHO but there are bigger defects to fix for now. And it's certainly too late for C++14.

Comment: @acidzombie24 Note that aggregate initialization is not done by any constructor. So there is no constructor which can be defaulted. When you want your class to behave like an aggregate the there must be no user-provided constructor. Otherwise your class is not an aggregate at all.

Comment: @Potatoswatter In what way do you think that there is a hole in the language? Consider: `struct X{ int a; X(int a); }; X x{10};` Should this perform aggregate initialization or call the constructor `X(int)`? By the language rules, `X` is not an aggregate and hence the constructor `X(int)` is called. Allowing aggregate initialization for such classes would cause a lot of trouble!

Comment: @MWid The "hole" is that you can't get the "default" behavior back with `= default`. It's only a vague complaint; I don't have a useful fix.